# iOS-Is there any method available for fetching CTCoreMessage with specific key words from CTCoreAccount or CTCoreFolder in Mailcore library?

Tags: ios, search, gmail, inbox, mailcore

I am developing one IOS Application in which i am integrate Gmail via Mailcore library, Now I want add search functionality for Inbox for which user can search their Email Subject and Body. But i am not aware how to implement it. Can anyone help me out? Is there any sample source code for this in Mailcore?

Comment: please give me api link i want to develop same app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it has search functionality

http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/

Comment: Thanks Rahul but i cant download **Remail Project** it shows me the error in terminal **fatal: remote error: Repository not found** could you help me?

Comment: what have you entered in terminal?

Comment: first install mercurial for mac in your mac system then open terminal
then in terminal type cd desktop then type this hg clone https://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/ it should be downloaded on your desktop. Then read the instruction given on remail repository on how to build remail

Answer (score 0):

MailCore api I've developed same kind of app and have use it. They provide access to IMAP and SMTP servers. 
Download from here

https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/